# Error while running Quarkus Production Jar

Tags: java, quarkus, optaplanner, quarkus-rest-client

The application starts successfully when running the command `java -jar target/quarkus-app/quarkus-run.jar`

While consuming the API from the external source, I got the `500` response, and below is the log got from the terminal.

```
ERROR [org.opt.cor.imp.sol.DefaultSolverManager] (pool-2-thread-1) Solving failed for problemId (c447ea05-f9f0-427f-a1de-093dc26100b0).: org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemor
yCompilerException: Cannot find the System's Java compiler. Please use JDK instead of JRE or add drools-ecj dependency to use in memory Eclipse compiler
 at org.kie.memorycompiler.jdknative.NativeJavaCompiler.compile(NativeJavaCompiler.java:75)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.AbstractJavaCompiler.compile(AbstractJavaCompiler.java:41)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad(KieMemoryCompiler.java:130)
        at org.kie.memorycompiler.KieMemoryCompiler.compileNoLoad(KieMemoryCompiler.java:102)
        ...
```

We are getting the same issue in both PC and EC2 instances.

While running the project in the Qurakus:dev, it is completely working fine.

Please help in understanding the issue and fixing it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Course timetabling and Conference scheduling examples are broken in OptaPlanner 8.0.0 final (Windows 10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65682295/course-timetabling-and-conference-scheduling-examples-are-broken-in-optaplanner)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Please use JDK instead of JRE

Looks like you're running it with a JRE instead of JDK.
Try running `java --version` and add its output to the question. See also Radovan's link - it was the same issue.

Comment: It throws this error when I am using Java 8. Then I tried installing Open JDK 11, then it worked like a charm.
Thanks for your help Geoffrey